# Когда нужен "?", а когда "/" в GET запросе?

Tags: get

Например запрос https://domain.ru/search_by_phone?phone_number или https://domain.ru/search_by_phone/phone_number, как будет правильнее и в каких случаях какой вариант использовать?

Comment: Через слеш - это часть URL запроса. А после ? идут параметры запроса.

Comment: The "http" scheme is used to locate network resources via the HTTP protocol. This section defines the scheme-specific syntax and semantics for http URLs.

http_URL = "http:" "//" host [ ":" port ] [ abs_path [ "?" query ]]